# How to access data from {string}

Tags: php

Some fields save data in the following way in one of my database field:

> {"per_meter_en-GB":"TEST_FOR_TEST","roll_40_en-GB":"","ask_for_price_en-GB":"YES"}

(* *Don't know how it's called so i wrote string in the title*)

How can i access data in particular for every "value".
One way could be to explode for every field but is there a better way to do this?

```
$ask_for_price_variable = [value from field];
if ($ask_for_price_variable == 'YES') {
    // Do something
}
```

**EDIT:** As i said i did not know how it was called "JSON" so i could not search for it. Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is json data. You can access it using `json_decode` in php

```
$json = '{"per_meter_en-GB":"TEST_FOR_TEST","roll_40_en-GB":"","ask_for_price_en-GB":"YES"}';

$data = json_decode($json,true);
$ask_for_price_variable = $data['ask_for_price_en-GB'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode

```
$str = '{"per_meter_en-GB":"TEST_FOR_TEST","roll_40_en-GB":"","ask_for_price_en-GB":"YES"}';
print_r(json_decode($str, true));
```

You need to study about JSON type and how to encode or decode to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r( json_decode('{"per_meter_en-GB":"TEST_FOR_TEST","roll_40_en-GB":"","ask_for_price_en-GB":"YES"}'));
```

to view the result , click run or hit f9, [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dqgw-gx5f)

Answer (score 0):

try [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function

```
$str = '{"per_meter_en-GB":"TEST_FOR_TEST","roll_40_en-GB":"","ask_for_price_en-GB":"YES"}';

$data = json_decode($str, true);

print_r($data);
```

**output:**

```
Array ( [per_meter_en-GB] => TEST_FOR_TEST [roll_40_en-GB] => [ask_for_price_en-GB] => YES )
```

here you can access required value from `$data` array eg. `echo $data['per_meter_en-GB'];` will output `TEST_FOR_TEST`